# Django doesn't load static files

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I have an Django project but I have problem with the static files. They are not loaded.

In my setting.py I have:

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + "grappelli/"

STATICFILES_DIRS = (INSTALLED_FOLDER + ('' if DEV_MACHINE else (SALES_COMPANY_CODE_LOWER + '/')) + '/Autralis/libStatic',)
```

I did next to load my styles:

```
ln -s /data /users/my_name/Projects/autralis/Autralis/libStatic/data
ln -s /users/my_name/Projects/autralis/Autralis/libStatic  /users/my_name/Projects/autralis/Autralis/static
```

And I get static folder as follows:

[image]

The links to styles in the base template are as follows :

`<link href="/static/autralis/css/base.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

and if I click on the link a get `page not found` as follows:

[image]

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Does your 'static' folder is inside an app ? It should be according to django doc : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#staticfiles-finders And you can check where Django is looking for your static with 'manage.py findstatic' (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-findstatic)

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an exemple from my Django project. Maybe it could help you ;)

My project tree :

[image]

In my **settings.py** file, I have :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
THEME_DIRS = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static", "Theme/")
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"), THEME_DIRS, ]

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static/')
```

And my HTML files get :

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load static %}

...
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% get_static_prefix %}{{ mytheme }}/css/Base_Accueil.css"/>
```

with context_processors.py file :

```
def GetTheme(request):
    return {'mytheme' : Theme.objects.values_list('favorite_theme').last()[0].encode("ascii")}
```

or more simple :

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load static %}

    ...
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/Base_Identity.css' %}"/>
```

Comment: Surely there is a nicer way to do this in 2021?! Which you do with `"{% static 'css/Base_Identity.css'%}"`, right?